# Migrate files with directories and sub directories

Tags: 7, migrations

I am having issues with migrating my files locally on my computer. Im using the migrate UI and my `source_dir = /Users/cwahlfeldt/Sites/dev.urbanaillinois.us/sites/default/files/` which is a full path to the files I'm trying to migrate. `destination_dir = public://`. Im getting the following errors when attempting a migration:

```
Informational   Undefined property: stdClass::$value File /Users/cwahlfeldt/Sites/drupal-7.x-dev/sites/all/modules/migrate/plugins/destinations/file.inc, line 704(file: /Users/cwahlfeldt/Sites/drupal-7.x-dev/sites/all/modules/migrate/plugins/destinations/file.inc, line 704)

Error   The specified file /Users/cwahlfeldt/Sites/dev.urbanaillinois.us/sites/default/files/ could not be copied to public://files: "copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory File /Users/cwahlfeldt/Sites/drupal-7.x-dev/sites/all/modules/migrate/plugins/destinations/file.inc, line 393"
```

The sources files directory has many sub directories within it and the `copy()` function thats used by the migrate module doesn't seem to want to take a directory. Is there a solution to this? Or is this caused by something else.

Answer (score 0):

How is destination_file mapped in your file migration? See https://www.drupal.org/node/1540106 for information on how the file options interact to determine the full destination filespec.